# Installing rvm without /dev/fd access

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

I have a sandboxed user account on a Linux machine that doesn’t have Ruby (shell privileges on a `name.com` hosted VM). I’d like to install Ruby, and I’m trying to use RVM to do so.

It also lacks Git or Subversion, which is going to pinch pretty soon. Oddly, it has something that purports to be `gcc`.

The RVM installer balks me because it can’t find `/dev/fs`. It suggests I put a symlink into `/dev` if it’s not there. I do not, nor ever will, have the privileges to do that.

I know this road will end abruptly some time, such as when some dependency tries to put something in the `/usr` tree, but I’d like to see how far I’d get.

Is there a workaround that will let me take this farther?